# Why the weird linebreaks while formatting quotes?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, markdown

[alt text http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/3773/captureyh.png](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/3773/captureyh.png)

**Why does the line break after some number of characters that only occupy half of the line width in the formatting mode?**

Comment: Good question - I know you can force a newline by adding `<br/>` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the "> " in the line, it's 40 characters at the longest (lines 4 and 7). Each linebreak occurs where adding one extra word would push it past 40 characters. It isn't 40 characters excluding the "> " because then you could fit `Donec sollicitudin scelerisque suscipit.` in one line.

The standard character width tends to be 80 characters for a full screen text, but the edit box is much smaller. It seems that to compensate, the number is reduced by half. However, I don't know how much it helps readability in the edit field, but that's the first impression I get, is that it is to reduce it to 40 characters per line.

Answer (score 0):

Because the whole quote (continuous lines preceded by `>`) is treated like a single paragraph. This is the same for non-quoted normal text: single line breaks are treated as a single space for formatting.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. What I am asking is why does the line break after `in` (the first line of paragraph) in formatting, while there is so much of space left on the line?

Comment: @Lazer: I did misunderstand... I thought you were questioning the difference between markup and rendered :-)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a stylistic ASCII choice by John Gruber; quoted text seems to be treated as shorter lines for some reason.

(at least when you click the quote button in the editor, I mean -- that's what it does.)